# How to return Tags with ListGroupResources AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

i trying to develop a script that retrieve all services from a resource group, actually i'm using the [ListGroupResources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/APIReference/API_ListGroupResources.html) from the aws-sdk, but the problem is i need the tags related to the services of resource groups and that method don't return the tags.

A intersting thing it's that in the resource groups AWS dashboard the related tags of the services are returned but not on the method.

So there's is a way to return all the services with all related tags to that services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using two differents API's

- Get all resources from the Resource Group using
  [ListGroupResources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/APIReference/API_ListGroupResources.html)
- Use [get-resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/get-resources.html) api using a list of arns that was retrieved from step one, get-resource api returns service with related tags.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in **two stages**:

1. Get list of resources using `ListGroupResources`
2. Iterate over the list and use [get-tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/resource-groups/get-tags.html) to get full tags for each resource.

Comment: Actually that api just brings me the tag from the resource group, not the tags related to the services.